# Netty io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.array() throws exception - direct buffer

Tags: java, tcp, jboss, netty

I wanted to print io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf as string. But io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.array() throws exception as follows.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: direct buffer
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.array(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:343)

Could some one help me to get the byte[] from byte io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have figured out a way to print the values. If anyone is interested,

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
buf.duplicate().readBytes(bytes);
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

Answer (score 2):

To print the contents of a ByteBuf as a string, you can use *buf.toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)*.

Answer (score 0):

Netty has a method for this

```
io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.hexDump(buf)
```